# How are addresses resolved by a compiler in a medium memory model?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, embedded, memory-address, memory-model

I'm new to programming small/medium memory models CPUs. I am working with an embedded processor that has 256KB of flash code space contained in addresses 0x00000 to 0x3FFFF, and with 20KB of RAM contained in addresses 0xF0000 to 0xFFFFF. There are compiler options to choose between small, medium, or large memory models. I have medium selected. My question is, how does the compiler differentiate between a code/flash address and a RAM address?

Take for example I have a 1 byte variable at RAM address 10, and I have a const variable at the real address 10. I did something like:

```
value = *((unsigned char *)10);
```

How would the compiler choose between the real address 10 or the (virtual?) address 10. I suppose if I wanted to specify the value at real address 10 I would use:

```
value = *((const unsigned char *)10);
```

?

Also, can you explain the following code which I believe is related to the answer:

```
uint32_t var32;     // 32 bit unsigned integer.
unsigned char *ptr; // 2 byte pointer.

ptr = (unsigned char *)5;
var32 = (uint32_t)ptr;
printf("%lu", var32)
```

The code prints 983045 (0xf0005 hex). It seems unrealistic, how can a 16 bit variable return a value greater than what 16 bits can store?

Comment: Firstly, the details are probably platform-specific (I have no idea what a "medium memory model" might be).  But it sounds like both flash and RAM are mapped into the same address space; `10` falls in the range you say that flash is mapped to, so it reads from flash.

Comment: Minor: Should use `printf("%" PRIu32, var32)` or `printf("%lu", (unsigned long) var32)`.

Comment: My compiler doesn't support PRIu32. Matter of fact, it doesn't even include <stdint.h> for uint32_t, I was just making an example for clarity. The actual type is an unsigned long, and it is a 32 bit variable on my compiler.

Comment: Medium memory model means 2 byte pointers for RAM/variables and 4 byte pointers for code.

Comment: can you clarify whether you mean [x86 medium memory model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model), or something else?

Comment: What compiler and CPU is this? There's no single definition of a "medium" memory model.

Comment: Renesas CPU, using the RL78,78K0R C compiler packaged with the CubeSuite IDE.

Comment: Can you link to some documentation that explains just what "medium memory model" means in this context?

Comment: If I could I wouldn't be asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

Read your compiler's documentation to find out details about each memory model.

It may have various sorts of pointer, e.g. `char near *` being 2-byte, and `char far *` being 4-byte. Alternatively (or as well as), it might have instructions for changing code pages which you'd have to manually invoke.

> how can a 16 bit variable return a value greater than what 16 bits can store?

It can't. Your code converts the pointer to a 32-bit int. , and `0xF0005` can fit in a 32-bit int. Based on your description, I'd guess that `char *` is only pointing to the data area, and you would use a different sort of pointer to point to the code area.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to comment on Matt's answer but my comment was too long, and I think it might be an answer, so here's my comment:

I think this is an answer, I'm really looking for more details though. I've read the manual but it doesn't have much information on the topic. You are right, the compiler has near/far keywords you can use to manually specify the address (type?). I guess the C compiler knows if a variable is a near or far pointer, and if it's a near pointer it generates instructions that map the 2 byte near pointer to a real address; and these generated mapping instructions are opaque to the C programmer. That would be my only guess. This is why the pointer returns a value greater than its 16 bit value; the compiler is mapping the address to an absolute address before it stores the value in var32. This is possible because 1) the RAM addresses begin at 0xF0000 and end at 0xFFFFF, so you can always map a near address to its absolute address by or'ing the address with 0xF0000, and 2) there is no overlap between a code (far) pointer and a near pointer or'd with 0xF0000. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 0):

My first take would be *read the documentation*, however as I had seen, it was already done.

So my assumption would be that you somehow got to work for example on a large existing codebase which was developed with a not too widely supported compiler on a not too well known architecture.

In such a case (after all my attempts with acquiring proper documentation failed) my take would be generating assembler outputs for test programs, and analysing those. I did this a while ago, so it is not from thin air (it was a 8051 PL/M compiler running on an MDS-70, which was emulated by a DOS based emulator from the late 80s, for which DOS was emulated by DOSBox - yes, and for the huge codebase we needed to maintain we couldn't get around this mess).

So build simple programs which would do something with some pointers, compile those without optimizations to assembly (or request an assembly dump, whatever the compiler can do for you), and understand the output. Try to cover all pointer types and memory models you know of in your compiler. It will clarify what is happening, and hopefully the existing documentations will also help once you understand their gaps this way. Finally, don't stop at understanding just enough for the immediate problem, try to *document* the gaps properly, so later you won't need to redo the experiments to figure out things you once almost done.